# Backbone events not firing, no errors and element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

Template:

```
<div class="view">
  <input id="todo_complete" type="checkbox" <%= completed ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %> />
  <label><%= title %></label>
  <button class="destroy"></button>
</div>
<input class="edit" value="<%= title %>" />
```

View:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  todoTpl: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

  events: {
    'dblclick label': 'edit',
    'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
    'blur .edit': 'close'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    console.log('Todo View initialized!');
    this.$el = $('#todo');
    console.log(this.$el);
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log('Todo View render started...');
    console.log(this.model.attributes);
    this.$el.html(this.todoTpl(this.model.attributes));
  },

  edit: function() {console.log('edit called!');},

  close: function() {console.log('close called!');},

  updateOnEnter: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

There are no events when the page loads, and I'm able to see the rendered template. However if I double click on the `label`, keypress on the `input` or blur the other input, nothing happens. I'm expecting to see a log in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You lose your event bindings when you:

```
this.$el = $('#todo');
```

You're not supposed to directly assign to the `$el` or `el` properties, you're supposed to call [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) instead:

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

Also, if you're going to be changing the view's `el` then there's no need for a `tagName` property. You could also specify the `el` when you create the view:

```
new TodoView({ el: '#todo' });
new TodoView({ el: $('#todo') });
```

If your `#todo` is actually the `<ul>` or `<ol>` then:

1. Leave the `tagName` alone.
2. Add the view's `el` to `$('#todo')` by calling `append` instead of calling `setElement`.

If this is the case then your code would look more like this:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  //...
  initialize: function() {
    console.log('Todo View initialized!');
    this.render();
  },
  //...
});

// And then where you create the view...
var v = new TodoView(...);
$('#todo').append(v.el);
```

Comment: Hm... it seems weird that id have to append the view to the DOM **without** using backbone. do i have to use jQuery to do this?

Comment: Normally that code would be in a router or your application initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this problem by adding `el` to the properties passed into `Backbone.View`:

```
 var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  // ...
  el: $('#todo')
  // ..
});
```